# Is it possible to use local table variables in a procedure inside an sql query contained in a VARCHAR variable?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE @temp_table_1 TABLE (id int identity(0, 1), col_1 varchar(50)), 
        @txtVar VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @temp_table_1
  SELECT col_1 FROM table_1  -- This table_1 is a real table in the database.

Set @txtVar = 'SELECT * FROM @temp_table_1'

EXECUTE (@txtVar)
```

The error I get is

> Declare variable @temp_table_1.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Set @txtVar = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column_value=''' + @var1 + ''''
```

[This](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/306) article will help you get a basic ideas of dynamic sql.

**EDIT**
It is not possible to use table variables in a dynamic query.
You have to use temporary table or [Use custom TABLE type](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/08/passing-table-variable-into-dynamic-sql.html).

***Temporary table***

```
 CREATE TABLE #temp_table_1 
  ( 
     id    INT IDENTITY(0, 1), 
     col_1 VARCHAR(50) 
  ) 

DECLARE @txtVar VARCHAR(MAX) 

INSERT INTO #temp_table_1 


SELECT col_1 
FROM   table_1 -- This table_1 is a real table in the database. 
SET @txtVar = 'SELECT * FROM  #temp_table_1' 

EXECUTE (@txtVar) 

DROP TABLE #temp_table_1
```

***Custom Table Type***

```
CREATE TYPE DefaultTable AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(0, 1), COL_1 VARCHAR(50))
GO

-- Fill a var of that type with some test data
DECLARE @MyTable DefaultTable
INSERT @MyTable 
SELECT col_1 FROM table_1 -- This table_1 is a real table in the database.

-- Now this is how you pass that var into dynamic statement
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM @MyTable', 
    N'@MyTable DefaultTable READONLY', 
    @MyTable
```

Comment: @Yogesh R: Sandy's correct.  Note *two* issues: 1) how to do string concatenation ("+"), and 2) be sure to quote the string literal before you execute the SQL statement.

Comment: @paulsm and Sandy: I have edited my question, please have a look and help me.