# pass IN sql stament to run to a procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create procedure to use `limit` option either `insert into`.. `with select`.. or `create table as select`.....

I want to use `limit` to insert only 500K records at a time so I am using while loop I set count3 this time as i am trying to insert 1.5mil records.

```
call proc1( with long sql statement......................)


DELIMITER //               
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1(IN sqllines text)               
   BEGIN    

   DECLARE valFrom INT;                   
   DECLARE valTo   INT;                         
   DECLARE count INt  default 0;                

       SET @sqlin = sqllines;         
       SET valFrom = 0;          
       SET valTo = 500000;          
       SET @sql = ('@sqlin LIMIT valFrom , valTo');      

 WHILE count < 3 
 DO  

  PREPARE stmt from @sql;           
  EXECUTE stmt;       

  SET valFrom = valFrom+500000;          
  SET valTo = valTo+500000;           
  set count = count + 1;            

END WHILE;           

END;              
//          
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve by splitting that into 3 iterated inserts? its the same (even sligth more) work for the server to perform those. And, where is your question?

Comment: I want all my create table as with select from ... and insert into table with select from …… want to use dynamically split procedure or function with limit option and with limit of 500k rows at time to avoid deadlock situation which is causing a lot trouble for my application users.

Comment: I cannot ask users to add limit manually every time they run as some of those queries are part of huge program.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but you cannot pass a variable into a dynamic-SQL statement in T-SQL.

You can find more information in a question that I myself posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206251/is-it-possible-to-use-local-table-variables-in-a-procedure-inside-an-sql-query-c). The answer here has detailed solution on this.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there a way i can call procedure along with my sql statements to dynamically split inserts with limit option and with 500K rows limit.

Comment: Import the data into a temp (same structure as original) table, let a job poll against that table every x seconds and only insert y rows into the origin table (and delete/mark them as done in the temp table)